# Deriving a composed matrix function

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, differential

I'm interested in deriving the following function, with respect to the matrix  $W$,

\begin{align}
R\left({G}; H\right) = 
     \log \bigg|{I} +s \cdot \big({G}^H{G}\big)^{-1}{G}^H{H}{H}^H{G}\bigg|.
\end{align}

where $G = WA$, and $G,W,A,H \in \mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$ and $s \in \mathbb{C}$.

I used matrixcalculus.org to reach the final answer, but I want to understand the way:

\begin{align} 
    \nabla_{W} R({W},{A}) =
    \bigg(s\!\cdot\!{A} \notag 
     \Big({I}+ s\!\cdot\!({{G}^H{G}\big)^{-1}
    {G}^H{H}{H}^H{G}}\Big)^{-1}\notag 
     \Big(2({G}^H{G})^{-1}{G}^H{H}{H}^H\Big)\notag 
    \Big({I}_M-{G}({G}^H{G})^{-1}{G}^H\Big)\bigg) ^H.
\end{align}

To facilitate the calculations I defined:

$Y = G^H G, \quad P = GY^{-1}G^H, \quad Z = PHH^H, \quad Q = I + s\cdot Z$

So, we have $R = \log \det Q$.

I used the differential method, but then I got stuck:

\begin{align}
\quad dR = Q^{-T} : dQ \\
\quad = Q^{-T} :s\cdot dZ  \\
\end{align}

And now I'm not sure how should I move forward.

what is $dZ, $what is $dP$, and what is $dY$? and how do I substitute them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$I'll keep most of your variable names, but I need to rename $H\to F,\:$ since $H^H$ is one keystroke away from disaster.

Also, in the complex domain, one typically uses Wirtinger derivatives (i.e. treating $\,\{dG,\,dG^H\}\,$ as independent variables).

First, note that the pseudoinverse can be used to shorten the expression
$$\eqalign{
G\LR{G^HG}^{-1}G^H = GG^+ \equiv P \\
}$$
The differential of this ortho-projector is well known
$$\eqalign{
dP &= \LR{I-P} \;dG\; G^+ + \LR{G^+}^H dG^H \LR{I-P} \\
}$$
Applying this to the current problem
$\LR{{\rm and\:ignoring\;the\;} dG^H {\rm\:term}}$
$$\eqalign{
dR &= Q^{-T}:dQ \\
 &= s\,Q^{-T}:dZ \\
 &= s\,Q^{-T}:dP\;FF^H \\
 &= \LR{sFF^HQ^{-1}}^T:dP \\
 &= \LR{sFF^HQ^{-1}}^T:\LR{I-P} \;dG\; G^+ \\
 &= \LR{s\,G^+FF^HQ^{-1}\LR{I-P}}^T:dG \\
 &= \LR{s\,G^+FF^HQ^{-1}\LR{I-P}}^T:dW\,A \\
 &= \LR{sAG^+FF^HQ^{-1}\LR{I-P}}^T:dW \\
\grad{R}{W} &= \LR{sAG^+FF^HQ^{-1}\LR{I-P}}^T \\
}$$

### Where did the factor of $\,2\,$ go?

This is a typical occurrence when dealing with Wirtinger derivatives.

As a simple example, consider the Frobenius norm (squared)
$$\phi = \frob{A}^2$$
When $A$ is $\sf real$, the gradient wrt $A$ is
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A:A \\
d\phi &= 2A:dA \\
\grad{\phi}{A} &= 2A \\
}$$
But when $A$ is $\sf complex$, the Wirtinger gradient wrt $A$ is
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A^* : A \\
d\phi &= A^*:dA \\
\grad{\phi}{A} &= A^* \\
}$$
BTW, this is also the reason why the (outer) Hermitian conjugate in your result has been replaced by a simple transpose in my result.

To reorder the matrices, you can take advantage of the identity
$$ \det(I+AB) \;=\; \det(I+BA) $$
before differentiating.

Comment: Can you explain why the term $G^+FF^H$ comes before $Q^{-1}$, unlike my result?
And, where has the constant $2$ gone to?

Comment: Huge thanks. Your contribution is priceless!